# How to launch Git bash in ConEmu from SublimeText?

Tags: conemu

I tried to use Terminal Plugin for ST3, like that

```
{
"terminal": "D:/Mega/SOFT/ConEmu/ConEmu.exe",
"parameters": ["C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/sh.exe"]
}
```

Sh.exe launches, but I can't pass "--login -i" parameters to it.

```
{
"terminal": "D:/Mega/SOFT/ConEmu/ConEmu.exe",
"parameters": ["C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/sh.exe --login -i"] // not working
}
```

/cmd {Git bash} and other switches also don't work here

Comment: Use short name for "Program Files" or correct double quotes around path with spaces.

Comment: Unfortunately neither "\"C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/sh.exe\" --login -i" nor "%ProgramFiles%/Git/bin/sh.exe" does not work at all, ConEmu does not pass "--login -i" parameters to sh.exe, instead these parameters applies to conemu.exe and that throws an error "no switch --login".

Comment: ConEmu could be launched with any terminal using parameters "/cmd {script}", but this is possible in Win links . I'm not so good at it, but I think ST3 Terminal plugin uses cmd.exe to launch another terminal. And there is no "/cmd" switch for ConEmu via cmd.exe, and no ConEmu {script} could be used in this way.

Comment: So, my question could be rephrased to "How to launch Git bash in ConEmu from cmd.exe?".

Comment: I've said **short** name! E.g. `PROGRA~1`. And you may easily check exact command line poised to ConEmu from TaskManager. I believe it's wrong.

Comment: Thanks, that really helped. I did not know about short names before you replied.

Comment: Also I've found a way to pass ConEmu scripts correctly - `"parameters": ["/cmd", "{Git bash}", "-cur_console:n"]`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
{
    "terminal": "D:/Mega/SOFT/ConEmu/ConEmu.exe",
    "parameters": ["/cmd", "%ProgramFiles%/Git/bin/sh.exe", "--login", "-i"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**That's work for me:**

```
{
  "terminal": "C:\\Program Files\\ConEmu\\ConEmu64.exe",
  "parameters": ["-run", "bash"]
}
```